# Solution to Install KODI 16.1 on Linux Ubuntu is required

Tags: system-installation, versions, kodi

I have run into 3 older machines that just can't handle Kodi 17. It runs, but so slow it's not an option to run it.

The steps I found to install Kodi 16.1 don't work.  How can you get 16.1 that I installed weeks ago when 17 was still in beta? I was able to get 16.1 (again on an older system with Linux) a few weeks ago.  It works great.  Now a few weeks later and I can't get 16.1 on a Linux machine.  I've spent hours trying to find a way. I have the same slow functioning Kodi on this machine.  These machines will probably never run Kodi 17 or higher. Someone must be able to give clear directions that answer how to install 16.1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify, which Ubuntu version you are using, but for 16.10 is Kodi 16.1 available in official (universe) repo:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/kodi

Depending of your Ubuntu version you may use different strategies to install it.

For 16.04 is even Kodi 15.2 available:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kodi